# Table in HTML not presented correctly

Tags: html

My code generates the following html file. As you can see the table tag is at the beginning of the code, but when we display it in a browser, the table is always at the end of the page. Can any one explain why it happens?

```
<table border = '1'><tr><td>count(*)</td></tr><tr><td>3616</td> </tr>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>Project 1B</title><meta http-equiv="Content- Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /></head>
    <body>

    <form method="GET">
        <p><h3>Project 1B: Queries</h3></p>
        <p>Type an SQL query in the following box:
   </p>

    <TEXTAREA NAME="area" ROWS=20 COLS=100>select count(*) from Movie;
    </TEXTAREA>
       <p>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
      </p>
    </form>

    <hr />

    <h3>Report:</h3>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That's something I haven't seen in a long time. P.S. Put your `table` _inside_ `body`, please.

Comment: You should show us your code. And, what do you mean by ` display it in a browser,` view source or use something like "Web developer tools " in Chrome? the browsers will actually fix many errors while decoding the html

Comment: Thanks! but even if I put the table inside body, it still goes to the bottom

Comment: @Shiji.Jiang I think it is only the problem of HTML right? it should have nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's because your `<table>` tag appears before your `<html>` tag. Try changing your code to generate the `<html>` then the `<table>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one, it turns out that I forget to close the table tag and it does all the weird things.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Have a look in Chrome]

as I said, the browsers will actually fix many errors while decoding(parsing) the html